# Encrypting a short phrase into two keys. both with length of 32letters

Tags: encryption

It doesn't need to be crazy secure. I wanted to figure out if there's a popular practice when encrypting a short phrase (less than 32 letter long) into two keys (two strings 32 length). Doesn't need to be complicated. It's for a hobby project.

For example:

Key 1: `JFHEL1J2J1KD1FK4J4K3LA5D7EKSJX323`
Key 2: `1HFK6SJDHG2JEK3DHG5NRJG9HE5K3GJEH`
Combined result: `Hello World!`

So in other words, if two keys get combined, it reveals a sentence. I suppose a simple mod/hash could work, but do you guys know of anything fancy?

Comment: What do you mean by "encrypting ... into two keys"? $\;$

Comment: sorry! maybe I should've said encrypting into two seperate strings with length of 32

Comment: Sounds like you want to take a plaintext, and encrypt it into 2 different ciphertexts that need to be combined somehow to reveal the plaintext, correct?

Comment: Yes. Correct!!!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_sharing#t_.3D_n $\;$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Ricky Demer mentioned, the [Shamir Secret Sharing Scheme](http://www.moserware.com/2011/11/life-death-and-splitting-secrets.html) is information-theoretically secure ("crazy secure") and also, for the "trivial case" of "[all shares are necessary to recover the secret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_sharing#t_.3D_n)", very simple.

We add all the shares together with "non-carrying addition", and the sum is decoded into the decrypted message.
There are a huge variety of ways to "add" the shares, all of which are information-theoretically secure.
The most popular seem to be

- non-carrying base 26 sum, aka Vigenère cipher variant Beaufort
- non-carrying base ten sum
- non-carrying base 2 sum, aka XOR, aka Vernam cipher

One example: Sum three shares using using Vigenere sum, with A:=0, B:=1, C:=2, D:=3, etc.:

```
ymunl buxee -- share 1 from Alice
htous qrgph -- share 2 from Bob
czdel fdoss -- share 3 from Trent
-----------
HELLO WORLD -- total
```

(If your phrase was less than 32 letters long, perhaps you could pad it out to 32 characters with Xs or Zs).

Another example: Sum three shares using non-carrying base sixteen, with A:=ten, B:=eleven, etc.:
(using /dev/urandom and [some other random number generator](http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2001-10-25/))

```
f 8 1 2  6 4 4 0  0 2 9 7  d 7 1 6  9 a e b  6 5 5 e -- share 1 from Alice
0 1 2 3  4 5 6 7  8 9 9 9  9 9 9 9  9 9 9 9  9 9 9 9 -- share 2 from Bob
5 f 3 0  c 3 c 5  e 4 0 0  f 7 c 0  5 f f 8  7 6 4 a -- share 3 from Trent
----------------------------------------------------
4 8 6 5  6 c 6 c  6 f 2 0  5 7 6 f  7 2 6 c  6 4 2 1 -- total

48  65   6c  6c   6f  20   57  6f   72  6c   64  21 (paired up)
 H   e    l   l    o        W   o    r   l    d   ! (decoded using ASCII)
```

(If your phrase was less than 16 characters long, perhaps you could pad it out to 16 characters with 0x20 space characters or 0x00 null characters, giving 32 character shares).

EDIT: Oh, you're making physical objects, rather than sending text messages?

When making physical objects to encrypt some short phrase,
I think that visual cryptography is a lot more fun.

The [visual cryptography system described by Dirk Rijmenants](http://users.telenet.be/d.rijmenants/en/visualcrypto.htm)
can be done with ink on normal transparency paper, or holes drilled through metal,
to do the XOR operation.
(Is there a way to make the leftover "random background" less distracting ?).

The [visual cryptography system used in the "amulets" of Henry Segerman](http://www.segerman.org/misc_art.html)
uses linearly polarizing filters to to do the XOR operation.

[image: Segerman amulets apart]
[image: Segerman amulets together]

[image]

Perhaps a tiny bitmap font would be useful.
[a](http://mckoss.com/jscript/tinyalice.htm) [b](http://robey.lag.net/2010/01/23/tiny-monospace-font.html) [c](http://www.dafont.com/bitmap.php) [d](http://kottke.org/plus/type/silkscreen/) [e](http://www.massmind.org/techref/datafile/charsets.htm) [f](http://blog.kenperlin.com/?p=6804) [g](http://www.fontriver.com/font/tiny/) [h](http://www.squaregear.net/fonts/tiny.shtml) [i](http://fontpro.com/proggy-tiny-font-14827) [k](http://www.alvit.de/blog/article/25-best-license-free-pixelfonts)

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer! I actually went a head and thought of XOR and created binaryrings.com
I came back to see that there was an answer to my question. It's a relief that I was on a right track ;)
Hopefully, I will be using this for my engagement ring